# Dispose a imported DLL

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

In my code, I'm importing a DLL using `[DllImport("OTVPlayer.dll")]` and using its methods. How can I dispose this DLL after using?

Comment: This is not necessary. The P/Invoke marshaler takes care of unloading DLLs for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that via `DllImport`.

You will have the resort to the native `LoadLibrary` and load the function pointers (into Delegate's) from there. You can unload the library once you are finished using the function pointers.

Comment: In a littlebit newbee to .net. can you give me more details please

Comment: Google on how to use LoadLibrary in .NET. It is too much to explain, and I have no context.